# Child div not taking parent div height

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have a div with two floated elements inside it.  I want the elements to have a line between them a 1px border.  The contents of one of the div is constant in height and the other variable in height.  That is the first has one line (number 10, 20, 30 etc) and the second div might have one, two, three etc lines (text that runs accross the lines.

I've been playing about with this for ages and can't get it to work.

```
.tablecol1{
    display:inline;
    width:17%;
    float:left;*/
    max-width: 40px;
    font-size:14pt;
    word-wrap: break-word
    background-color:#ffffff;
    padding-left:1%;
    }
.tablecol2{
    display:inline;

    width:80%;
    float:left;
    font-size:11pt;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    border-left:1px solid #000000;
            padding-left:1%;
    }   
.rowHolder{
    overflow:hidden;
/*  width:100%;*/
    border-top:solid 1px #000000;
    font-size:11pt;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color:#fccfff;
    position:relative;
}
.cleaner {
    clear:both;
    height:1px;
    font-size:1px;
    border:none;
    margin:0; padding:0;
    background:transparent;
}
```

divs are

```
<div class="rowHolder">
    <div class="tablecol1">
        <span class="bigtime">09</span> <span class="smalltime">00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tablecol2"></div>
    <div class="cleaner"></div>
</div>
<div class="rowHolder">
    <div class="tablecol1">
        <span class="bigtime">10</span> <span class="smalltime">00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tablecol2">
        <div class="appointment" style="background-color:#fab88e">
            10:03 | Sight test | Alan Orr | BB could be the code or comment added
        </div>
        <div class="appointment" style="background-color:#fab88e">
            10:30 | Walk in | John Smith | NP or something about reported sore red eye
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cleaner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle? How can the child divs inherit a height when there is no height set on the parent?

Comment: you're missing a closing div tag. Is the 'cleaner' div supposed to be inside the 'tablecol2' div?

Comment: Where exactly do you want the border lines?  to the left of the "col" or to the left of the "cells"?

Comment: Hi Justin, I want a vertical line between tablecol1 and tablecol2

Comment: Hi Paddyd - I messed up copying the HTML across, I've ammended it now

Comment: Your `appointment` divs aren't closed

Comment: I've never used jsFiddle before but I think this is the correct thing: http://jsfiddle.net/user1616338/7kfCS/

Comment: the appointment divs are closed in the actual code you can see in the jsfiddle link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to solve your problem:

```
.tablecol2{
    min-height: 21px;
    ...
```

As the `.tablecol2` is `float: left` it cannot inherit the height of the parent div.
This code will set the minimum height, so the separator line will be always rendered.

Here is the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/vRAPd/

Comment: Hi thanks for this it seems to work okay.  The line height needed adjusting a bit though when I put in in the live code

Answer (score 0):

This won't give the row the height that you were asking about, but I believe it does give you the final result you were looking for.

adding:

```
margin-right: -1px;
border-right: 1px solid black;
```

to the first column allows it to `share` a border with the second column.  So event when the first column wraps at small screen sizes as it does now in your example, the shared border will extend the full height of the row with no visible gaps.

*minor note*: you were missing a semi-colon here: `word-wrap: break-word` in `.tablecol1`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7kfCS/5/)

**CSS**

```
.tablecol1 {
    display: inline;
    width: 17%;
    float: left;
    font-size: 14pt;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding-left: 1%;
    margin-right: -1px;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
.tablecol2 {
    display: inline;
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
    font-size: 11pt;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
    padding-left: 1%;
}
.rowHolder {
    overflow:hidden;
    border-top:solid 1px #000000;
    font-size:11pt;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color:#fccfff;
    position:relative;
}
.cleaner {
    clear:both;
    height:1px;
    font-size:1px;
    border:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background:transparent;
}
```

Comment: Hi  thanks for this.  I'd tried a similar thing already but I couldn't get the two things to line up accurately.  It depended a lot on which browser I was using.  Whilst this kind of works it's a bit of a fudge and I don't think it is really the solution

Comment: Could you be more specific?  it works in safari, chrome and firefox. Haven't yet tried it in that other browser.

Comment: if was FF 23.0.1  I tried it in.  When you zoom in the lines weren't aligned.  At small resolution it didn't show up.  I'll try again just to check I didn't have some kind of typo.

Comment: Hmmm - I don't see if here.  BTW: with the min-height solution, you will get a gap if you allow column 1 to wrap.  I tried that first myself then noticed the resize problem.  If you are planning on changing your markup to keep col1 from wrapping that should work ok for you.